# Join statement order of operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

Given the following 3 way  join

```
select t1.* from t1
left join t2 on t1.fk = t2.pk
join t3 on t2.fk = t3.pk
```

If the join between t2 and t3 failed, would the row from the successful join between t1 and t2 be returned? If the order of operation goes from left to right, I assume not,  but if it's evaluated from right to left (t3 is joined to t2 first) then t1 will still be returned even when the former failed.

How does it work?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The placement of the `ON` clauses controls the **logical** order of evaluation.

So first the `t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.fk = t2.pk` happens. The result of this join is a virtual table containing all the matching rows from `t1, t2` and (because it is a left outer join) any non matched `t1` rows are also preserved with null values for the `t2` columns.

This virtual table then participates in the next join. `JOIN t3 ON t2.fk = t3.pk`

Any `t2` records that do not match rows in `t1` are not part of the virtual table output from the first stage so won't appear in the final result. Additionally this inner join on `t2.fk = t3.pk` will lose any `NULL` values of `t2.fk` effectively turning your whole thing back into inner joins.

Logical Query Processing is explained well [by Itzik Ben Gan here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140906155258/http://www.sql.co.il/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf)

Comment: Answers to the point and is very comprehensive in the explanation. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Nice and easy explanation i'm wondering does the same order of operation applies to `sqlite`?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar - I haven't used SQLLite but if it adheres to standard (ANSI/ISO) SQL it will.

Comment: Hoping it adheres. Ok so what will happen if i modify the above query as
`select t1.* from t1
inner join t2 on t1.fk = t2.pk
left join t3 on **t1.fk** = t3.pk`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar The result of the inner join on t1 and t2 forms a virtual table. Call this `vt1`. Then that virtual table is joined onto t3. Any rows in the virtual table vt1 that didn't match anything in t3 are preserved in the result with NULL for the t3 columns.

Comment: Martin did you noticed the `left join` i have changed t2.fk = t3.pk to t1.fk = t3.pk!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar - Yes. The virtual table `vt1` contains all columns from both  t1 and t2.

Comment: So what i understand that the if we have lets say 2 joins. The second join will be **applied to** the virtual table being obtained from first join? Also `t2.fk = t3.pk to t1.fk = t3.pk` does both are equal?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar - Yes to the first part. The second join will be applied to the virtual table being obtained from first join. No to the second part as there is nothing that guarantees that the values of t2.fk and t1.fk are the same so the query may return different results but this doesn't change the logical description.

Comment: Actually what i mean to ask is that whether we compare the `base table` column or the `virtual table` column in second left join the results will be same? Assuming as in example comparing only pk's and fk's.