# How to express nested SELECTS as a simpler JOIN

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables:

```
customers:    id,          name
transactions: id_customer, id_item
items:        id,          name
```

I want to write a simple query that will return the names of all customers who ordered an item with the name 'apple'

I know I can do something like:

```
SELECT
  name
FROM
  customers
WHERE id IN (SELECT
               id_customer
             FROM
               transactions
             WHERE id_item IN (SELECT
                                 id
                               FROM
                                 items
                               WHERE name = 'apple'))
```

This may not be too bad, but it seems convoluted and like there might be a more straightforward way to do this with a join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely better to use a join in this case. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.name
FROM 
    customers A INNER JOIN
    transactions B ON A.id = B.id_customer INNER JOIN
    items C ON B.id_item = C.id
WHERE C.name = 'apple'
```

In this way, only customers who placed an order containing `'apple'`s will be shown.

Comment: You need `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Correct. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Is there a performance difference between these two queries? I assume your way is faster but I'm not sure why

Comment: Indeed. Especially if the relations between the tables are explicitly declared with foreign keys. In this way the DBMS will only check for matching keys instead of scanning the entire tables to satisfy the nested `SELECT`s first.

Comment: Which inner join is evaluated first?

Comment: JOINs are evaluated in their sequential order in the query. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655988/join-statement-order-of-operation) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Use Join case, this a best way to approach.

```
Select C.name from Customers C 
Inner Join Transaction T on C.id = T.id_customer 
Inner Join Items I on T.id_items = I.id
where I.name = "Apple"
```

Above query will return the names of all customers who ordered "Apple".

Comment: Thanks. I think as in GigiSan's answer, there should be a DISTINCT